# why is my function that's using arrays and returning a boolean result not working

Tags: vb.net

Why am i getting the following error when i run the following function in vb.net?

file.vb on line ? No errors, but compilation failed?

> vbnc : Command line : error VBNC99999: Unexpected error: There has
>   been an internal error in the compiler: Consistency check failed   at
>   vbnc.Compiler.VerifyConsistency (Boolean result, Span Location)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   vbnc.AssemblyDeclaration.ResolveCode (vbnc.ResolveInfo Info) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at vbnc.Compiler.Compile_Resolve ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at vbnc.Compiler.Compile ()
>   [0x00000] in :0  Compilation took 00:00:00.8679190

```
Function launchSequenceChecker(systemNames As List(Of String), stepNumbers As List(Of Integer)) As Boolean 

dim a,b,c as integer
dim len1  as integer
dim len2 as integer
Dim answer As Boolean

len1 = systemNames().count
len2 = stepNumbers().count

for c =0 to len1-1
    dim systemNames(c) as string
    dim stepNumbers(c) as integer
next c

for a  = 0 to len1-1
    for b = a to len2
        if string.compareordinal(systemNames(a),systemNames(b+1)) = true then
            if stepNumbers(a) < stepNumbers(b+1) then
                return false
            end if
        end if
    next b
next a
```

return true

End Function

Comment: You have multiple issues in your code. First, `next c` is not declared. Second, the length of a list is given to you by using for example `systemNames.Count`. Third, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.110).aspx for using String.Compare.

Comment: Thanks, but i changed it and see the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your `For` loops specify `a` and `b` as the loop counters but your Next statements specify `b` and `c`. I'm guessing that that is the issue. I can see other issues with the code but that addresses your specific question I think.